# Why I get the html code, using active_admin gem with paperclip gem?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

When I add any image to my post **from active admin panel**, i get html code like this(for example):

```
<img class="img-rounded" src="/system/photos/images/000/000/028/original/ruby.png" alt="Ruby" /></br>
```

and I see **alt:** *Ruby* on my page, when I click on this link I don't see my image.

But I add any image to my post **from my blog page** I get link like this:

```
<img class="img-rounded" src="/system/photos/images/000/000/026/original/ruby.png?1490011829" alt="Ruby" /></br>
```

and when I click on this link I see my image. *Why? What need I do?*

Comment: and does the first image exist? routes are different 028 - 026

Comment: I try add images to my post, from activ admin panel and from my post page, then I remove it, becouse its have diffrent paths

Comment: if I add any image from admin active panel I get the link that don't link to my image like ../ruby.png, but ../ruby.png?1490011829 link to my image